# What is more promising: the development of nuclear space tugs (Roskosmos, etc.) or the improvement of existing ones?

Tags: space-tug

There are a lot of things in space now that require the use of space tugs. Many companies are developing their space tugs. For several years there has been talk of a nuclear space tug. Are all these developments needed? Or whatever you need to do can be done with something like this https://www.skyrora.com/space-tug ?

Comment: As posed, this question is likely to get opinion-based answers, or even be closed because it is phrased to attract such answers. More in line with Stack Exchange would be to ask something like "What are the advantages and disadvantages to nuclear power for a space tug..."  I would also be a bit more specific about what you see the space tug being for -- is it to work in LEO, or GEO or somewhere else? for instance

Comment: Can you rewrite this so that fact-based answers can be written? "Are all these developments needed?" is not a useful question to ask in a free-market capitalism situation. Everybody competes, there are always duplicate development efforts, and sometimes not even the best one wins!

Comment: I would ask this so that it asks for the state of the currently (2021) running or planned projects. That will be already likely okay. I also don't believe the specified stats of the company, what type of nuclear engine can 3.5kN thrust? It is surely not an ion engine, it must work thermodynamically, but so chemical means would be better. Maybe it could some like a "project orion", but space-only and small.

Comment: @peterh-ReinstateMonica Skyrora's tug is chemical, HTP/kerosene (with an added gimmick of making the fuel from plastic waste).

Comment: @ChristopherJamesHuff Thanks! But, so I think it does not have a very much delta-v, particularly if it has to move things on orbit.

Comment: You can't just take any two tugs and expect them to be directly comparable, any more than you can for any two ground vehicles. What specific nuclear tug do you have in mind that would be at all comparable to Skyrora's tiny little smallsat tug?

Comment: @peterh-ReinstateMonica it doesn't necessarily need much delta-v. Perhaps it just needs to circularize a satellite in low Earth orbit, phase to another satellite in the same orbit, and give it a 100 m/s deorbit kick. Not something you'd want to use a nuclear tug for, even if it didn't involve dropping a reactor somewhere on Earth.

Comment: @ChristopherJamesHuff Nuclear tugs with ion drives could have delta v in hundreds km/s. Imagine a nuclear-powered VASIMR-based tug. Unfortunately the greens would likely reject the idea, but they reject everything and the world needs development. But I think it is quite a good idea. Such a single tug, even this chemical one, could eliminate a lot of such satellites! And Musk dad could send tens in the space between two starlink launches.

Comment: What things in space require the use of space tugs? What space tugs exist today?